# Radeon 9800 pro driver ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, video

I'm new to askubuntu and I have a question that I cant seem to find an answer for. I may be getting a ATI Radeon 9800 Pro (unless some one can recommend me a better card) I would like to know if the card has good drivers on Ubuntu 12.04 because my older card doesn't have proprietary drivers in 12.04 but they were in my previous OS 11.10.

I would be using the card for Steam, tf2 maybe Amnesia (if I've got the stomach for it) This would be for a low end build, AMD Athlon 3300+ and 1 or 2GB of RAM. Based on that list of parts could some one suggest a better card, if the 9800 Pro is good or if there are drivers or not for the card on 12.04. (I think I forgot something but we'll cross that bridge when we get to it)

Answer (score 0):

AMD stopped providing support for Radeon 9800 in 2009, whihc means there won't be any proprietary drivers available. The card should work with the free radeon driver, but that still has some way to mature before becoming a gaming alternative to the proprietary ATI driver.

[benchmarks](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_r600g_compete12&num=1)

A more recent ATI or Nvidia card would probably be a better choice for gaming.